# Dependency conflict while upgrading Gentoo

Tags: upgrade, gentoo, dependencies, emerge, portage

When I tried to upgrade my Gentoo system, I had got following errors:

```
WARNING: One or more updates/rebuilds have been skipped due to a dependency conflict:

sys-libs/zlib:0

  (sys-libs/zlib-1.2.11-r1:0/1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    sys-libs/zlib[minizip] required by (dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.7.1-r2:5/5.7::gentoo, installed)
                  ^^^^^^^ 
    sys-libs/zlib[minizip] required by (net-im/psi-1.3:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                  ^^^^^^^ 

media-libs/libvpx:0

  (media-libs/libvpx-1.5.0:0/3::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    >=media-libs/libvpx-1.5:=[svc] required by (dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.7.1-r2:5/5.7::gentoo, installed)
                              ^^^ 
    >=media-libs/libvpx-1.5:0/3=[svc] required by (dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.7.1-r2:5/5.7::gentoo, installed)
                                 ^^^ 

dev-qt/qtcore:5

  (dev-qt/qtcore-5.7.1-r3:5/5.7::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    ~dev-qt/qtcore-5.7.1[icu] required by (dev-qt/qtwebkit-5.7.1:5/5.7::gentoo, installed)
                         ^^^ 

media-video/ffmpeg:0

  (media-video/ffmpeg-3.3.5:0/55.57.57::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    >=media-video/ffmpeg-2.6.3[webp,v4l] required by (net-im/qtox-1.11.0:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                               ^^^^ ^^^ 

dev-libs/libpcre:3

  (dev-libs/libpcre-8.41:3/3::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    >=dev-libs/libpcre-8.38[pcre16,unicode] required by (dev-qt/qtcore-5.7.1-r3:5/5.7::gentoo, installed)
                            ^^^^^^         

app-text/poppler:0

  (app-text/poppler-0.56.0:0/67::dantrell-gnome, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    app-text/poppler:=[qt5] required by (app-office/texmaker-4.5-r2:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                       ^^^ 
    app-text/poppler:0/67=[qt5] required by (app-office/texmaker-4.5-r2:0/0::gentoo, installed)
                           ^^^ 


!!! The following installed packages are masked:
- dev-vcs/monotone-1.0-r4::gentoo (masked by: package.mask)
/usr/portage/profiles/package.mask:
# Pacho Ramos <pacho@gentoo.org> (28 Dec 2017)
# Multiple build failures and bugs (#634316), fails with recent lua
# (#434242), init script is buggy (#496724), bash completion files installed
# wrongly (#526280), fails with newer botan (#537572). Removal in a month.

For more information, see the MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge
man page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.
```

How can I resolve this dependency conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the `^^^`'s indicate is that there are package dependencies which are expecting certain USE flags to be enabled. For example:

```
sys-libs/zlib:0

  (sys-libs/zlib-1.2.11-r1:0/1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    sys-libs/zlib[minizip] required by (dev-qt/qtwebengine-5.7.1-r2:5/5.7::gentoo, installed)
                  ^^^^^^^ 
    sys-libs/zlib[minizip] required by (net-im/psi-1.3:0/0::gentoo, installed)
```

In the above example, `qtwebengine` and `psi` depend on `zlib` compiled with the `minizip` USE flag.

To address this, you need to add the expected USE flag(s) to your `make.conf` In older Gentoo installations the file is located at `/etc/make.conf`, and on newer installs at `/etc/portage/make.conf`.

This file contains a `USE` variable with a space-separated list of flags. So first check if the flag in question is in the list, but prefixed with a dash (-) which means to disable the flag. If so, you'll need to remove the dash to enable the flag. On the other hand, if the flag is not listed, then you simply need to add it.

Comment: I agree with the general premise of the answer, but I would recommend putting per-package USE flags in `package.use`, as (for example) you may not want to add minizip support to every package that has that flag available. My `make.conf` only has stuff that I really want in every package that supports it, like `dbus`, `caps`, etc.